# Remove quotes from string inside of array

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

`$string = '"excludeIF":["miniTrack","isTriangleHanger","tubeTrack","boxTrack"]';`

I need to get rid of the " that are inside of the `[]` array so it looks like this:

`$string = '"excludeIF":[miniTrack, tubeTrack, boxTrack]';`

I was trying some regex but I kept getting rid of all of the quotes.

Comment: This question has [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) written all over it. Can you explain how you got this string in the first place and why you're trying to remove quotes from it? *hint* the fact that you use the word ___array___ to describe a string is a huge indicator of the X in this Y.

Comment: That sure looks like you are trying to destroy a good JSON string

Comment: look at OP's previous question for a better understanding of what he is doing. Some one might even be inclined to close it as a dupe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular example:

```
$string = '"excludeIF":["miniTrack","isTriangleHanger","tubeTrack","boxTrack"]';
preg_match("/((?<=\[).*(?=\]))/", $string, $match);
$change = str_replace('"', "", $match[0]); 
$result = preg_replace("/$match[0]/", $change, $string);
```

What this does is it gets the content inside the square brackets, removes the quotes, then replaces the original content with the cleaned content.

This may run into errors if you have the exact same string outside of square brackets later on, but it should be an easy fix if you understand what I've written.

Hope it helps.

PS. It would also help if you showed us what regexes you were trying, as you were, perhaps, on the right path but just had some misunderstandings.

Comment: if you look at his previous question, you will see this is not really an answer to his issues

Comment: I'm only answering the question to which I see and has been posted.

Comment: I suggest you familiarize yourself with the [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @nogad Well, in the event that someone so happens to also be looking to remove quotes inside a string, this question will have answered it, despite it not actually answering what OP is wanting answered.

Answer (score 1):

So yeah I agree with the comment about the XY Problem, but I would still like to try help.

```
$string = '"excludeIF":["miniTrack","isTriangleHanger","tubeTrack","boxTrack"]';
```

You will now need to find the start and end positions of the string that you want edited. This can be done by the following:

```
$stringPosition1 = strpos($string,'[');
$stringPosition2 = strpos($string,']');
```

Now you have the correct positions you are able to do a `substr()` to find the exact string you want edited.

```
$str = substr($string,$stringPosition1,$stringPosition2);
```

From here you can do a simple `str_replace()`

```
$replacedString = str_replace('"','',$str);
$result = '"excludeIF":' . $replacedString;
```

It is an excellent idea to look at the PHP docs if you struggle to understand any of the above functions. I truly believe that you are only as good at coding as your knowledge of the language is. So please have a read of the following documents:

- Str_pos: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
- Sub_str: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
- Str_replace: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score -1):

test this code:

```
<?php
$string = '"excludeIF":["miniTrack","isTriangleHanger","tubeTrack","boxTrack"]';
$str_array = str_split($string);
$string_new = '';
$id = 0;
foreach ($str_array as $value) {
    if($value == '[' || $id != 0){
        $id = ($value != ']') ? 1 : 0;
        $string_new .= ($value != "\"") ? $value : '' ;
    } else {
        $string_new .= $value;
    }
}
echo $string_new;
//RESULT "excludeIF":[miniTrack,isTriangleHanger,tubeTrack,boxTrack]
?>
```

Good luck!

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$string = '"excludeIF":["miniTrack","isTriangleHanger","tubeTrack","boxTrack"]';
$part = str_replace("\"","",(strstr($string,'[')));
$string = substr($string,0,strpos($string,'[')).$part;
echo $string;
?>
```

Other possible solution.

Fun with code!

Comment: do you think looping though every character is efficient?

Comment: No, but is a possible solution, no? Fun with code !